# Vagrant Provision on Host

Tags: shell, vagrant

This is part of my Vagrantfile:

```
  config.vm.provision :shell, :privileged => false, :path => "bootstrap.sh"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  #config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 8443
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3030, host: 3030
```

Right after this, I want to run a few commands on the Host machine (meaning, the same 'vagrant up' would be running a provision script, or inline, on the host). How would I do that ?

Answer (score 4):

You can check out this Vagrant plugin I've written:

https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers

Comment: This is good, but does it mean that there is no way to run commands directly with no need for plugins ?

Comment: to install this plugin there are lot of errors. Fix one error by googling , another appears. I would like that it would auto install what is missing

Answer (score 2):

Vagrant does not have a provisioner for the running scripts on the host right now.

This plugin looks promising: https://github.com/phinze/vagrant-host-shell

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to install some addition plugins, you can simply create bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
vagrant up
echo "success" //put here all you want
```